# How to merge short strings in a list into long strings

Tags: c#, list

Here I have a string list as follows:

```
List<string> str = new List<string> 
{ "1", "22", "3", "44", "55", "666666", "7777777", "8", "99" };
```

What I want is merging short strings into a long string of length less than n.

Expect:

```
n = 5
newlist = { "1223", "4455", "666666", "7777777", "899" };
```

Comment: So what solution did you come up with and what's wrong with it?

Comment: `foreach (item in sourceList) { if currentStringLength + itemLength > n then newList.add(currentString); currentString = item; else currentString += item }` ?

Comment: @AgentFire take note of _["Not all questions benefit from including code..."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_ and _[Is it always a good idea to demand the OP “post some code”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286760/585968)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> str = new() { "1", "22", "3", "44", "55", "666666", "7777777", "8", "99" };
    
    const int n = 5;
    
    List<string> newList = new();
    
    var newString = string.Empty;
    foreach (var s in str)
    {
        if ((newString.Length + s.Length) <= n)
        {
            newString += s;
            continue;
        }
        newList.Add(newString);
        newString = s;
    }
    
    newList.Add(newString); // Don't forget the last under length string
    Console.WriteLine(newList);
}

// Outputs  "1223", "4455", "666666", "7777777", "899"
// Also handles empty input strings
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the answer. [LINQ `.Aggregate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0) is alternative solution for `foreach` loop.

The `.Aggregate()` is able to use to iterate with the current value and next value.

1. Check `toBeAppended` value.

   1.1 If `toBeAppended.Length` > `n`, add the `current` value to the `result`. And you need to reset the `current` value.

   1.2 Else set the `current` with `toBeAppended`.
2. After the end of the interaction, make sure you need to add the last value to the `result`.

```cs
List<string> str = new List<string> { "1", "22", "3", "44", "55", "666666", "7777777", "8", "99" };
int n = 5;
var result = new List<string>();
        
var last = str.Aggregate("",
        (current, next) => 
        {
            var toBeAppended = current + next;
                        
            if (toBeAppended.Length >= n)
            {
                result.Add(current);
                current = next;
            }
            else
            {
                current = toBeAppended;
            }
                        
            return current; 
        });
        
result.Add(last);
```

[Sample Program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1jz00i)

Comment: Clever code, but personally I can't grok linq logic very quickly!